# How do I enable REST Metadata API?

Tags: metadata-api, rest, metadata

I am getting this error in Workbench when using the REST explorer:

```
API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG
message: The REST Metadata API is not enabled for this Organization.
errorCode: API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG
```

INFO: We are on OEM licensed Org through app exchange partner, but it is on enterprise edition and yes API is enabled for the profile in question.

**Can REST Metadata Api be enabled and if so how?**

P.S. Ultimate Problem trying to solve is how do I get a list of States by Country for use in a JS array, on another integrated PLatform? We have States&Countries enabled. I have created a separate Question for this!

Comment: What is the edition of the Salesforce org that where you intend to enable the Metadata API? If it is a Professional edition org, API access is unavailable by default and needs to be added explicitly at an an additional cost. You will need to get in touch with your Salesforce Account Executive to get this done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the features is being enabled in Winter 19 release. So if your sandbox is in Winter 19 you should not get this error anymore.
The official notes doesn't say explicitly, but you can read more about it here: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_api_meta_rest_deploy.htm
I have tried it and it works in Winter 19, while if I try to use it in a Summer 18 sandbox I get the same error message as the question

Comment: This answer would be improved if you add a link to release notes or something similar.