# Metadata API: any drawback when using REST instead of SOAP?

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata-api, rest

Is there any drawback on using Metadata API through REST (that became available since [Winter'19](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_api_meta_rest_deploy.htm))? I only see good things such as:

- Smaller payloads: probably improving performance reducing the network traffic.
- A bigger amount of deployment bundle: the .zip file size limit of 39 MB .zip that applies to SOAP deployments.

However, based on some amazing previous [answers](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/233284/45578) here and the [Salesforce DX Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_cli_config_values.htm), I noticed that SFDX CLI still defaults to SOAP.

I don't even understand REST is not becoming the default option in SFDX CLI.

Comment: I asked about it on social media. When I get a response, I'll circle back around.

Comment: With the majority of the payload being composed of the ZIP files that metadata API uses I'd be surprised if you see any meaningful difference in performance related to request/response size. The more important part would be compressing the request and accepting a compressed response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the response in the form of a [Tweet](https://twitter.com/ClaireSFDX/status/1267857763658391552?s=20):

> That is correct. We have data command updates, including this on our roadmap for the end of this year.

In other words, the DX team simply hasn't gotten to it yet. Obviously, Safe Harbor applies, but this should be pretty trivial, I imagine, since it already works with the flag.

Comment: Thanks a million Brian, especially for going the extra mile here. I agree, it sounds trivial, I guess they might just trying to be on the safe side.